# Can an abstract class be used as a reference type?

Tags: java, abstract

I'm not so sure what that would imply and my textbook is dancing around the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

}

class DeclaredClass extends AbstractClass {

}

AbstractClass c = new DeclaredClass();
```

The above is perfectly valid.

Comment: I thought you weren't allowed to instantiate an abstract class, or am I reading the last line incorrectly?

Comment: @nogame Have a closer look. The declared class is instantiated not the Abstract Class.

Comment: Oh, so if it were DeclaredClass c = new AbstractClass(); then it would be invalid?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is,

```
List a = new ArrayList();
```

Here `List` is a reference to an `ArrayList` object. So, the question means is it possible in case of Abstract Class?

Comment: List is an interface, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an abstract class in 2 ways:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {}
```

**1. Extending the Abstract class:**

```
    class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {}
    AbstractClass c = new ConcreteClass();
```

**2. Using Anonymous Class:**

```
    AbstractClass c = new  AbstractClass(){};
```